# ISODate fails to parse from Spring Boot JPA repo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot JPA Repository that finds a bunch of "things" in a MongoDB instance that has a field called "lastModified" which is an ISODate() as per the below.

```
{ "name": "a", "lastModified", "ISODate(2018-04-19T19:10:39.356574)" }
```

When I use a repository function like:

```
public List<Thing> findByName(String name);
```

I get a

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value 'ISODate(2018-04-18T18:38:42.635027)'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I have tried

- Creating separate setters and constructors that take each java.util.Date and
  String and do a converstion with a
  `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")`
- Using
  `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")` on the
  lastModified parameter on the Entity

Am I missing something about how Mongo does this conversion? I would expect it turns that ISODate into a simple string and passes it into the setLastModified(String name) function but I guess that's not the case?

Comment: Value `ISODate(2018-04-19T19:10:39.356574)` doesn't actually fit the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`, now does it? It has extra text, so include that in the pattern, like the `T` is included: `'ISODate('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')'`

Comment: @Andreas You escape stuff in the SimpleDateFormat with single quotes so 'T' is T as like 'at' would be at

Comment: `SSSSSS` doesn't work for [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), since `S` is *millisecond*, meaning that anything other than exactly 3 of them makes no sense, i.e. `SSS`. --- In [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `S` means *fraction-of-second*, so any number of them (1-9) makes sense.

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to tell me in that comment. I already know this, which is why I single-quoted `'ISODate('` and `')'`

Comment: Oh, you're trying to say that it passes the whole thing including the Type info as part of the string. I can try it but that seems wrong as I have other places with ISODate("2018-04-17T19:43:00Z") that work fine

Comment: ISODate is an internal Mongo type of a date object... I think the issue is that this date is "ISODate(2018-04-19T19:10:39.356574)" instead of ISODate("2018-04-17T19:43:00Z")... the insert was done as a string instead of a Date

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It will even parse `2018-04-19T19:10:39.356574` without any explicit formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just because the date was inserted as a string of "ISODate(2018-04-19T19:10:39.356574)" instead as a Date which would be like ISODate("2018-04-17T19:43:00Z")

Once I went and found and fixed the source of this data, it started working properly.